# Ardalis.Specification and Azure Cosmos Database : What is the place where the query is applied? Cosmos Database or Application Memory?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, specification-pattern

I am trying to implement Ardalis.Specification in .net core Web API application that uses Azure Cosmos Database

Below is my Specification definition

```cs
public class ToDoItemSearchSpecification : Specification<ToDoItem>
{
    public ToDoItemSearchSpecification(
        string title = "",
        int pageStart = 0,
        int pageSize = 50,
        string sortColumn = "title",
        SortDirection sortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending,
        bool exactSearch = false
    )
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
        {
            if (exactSearch)
            {
                Query.Where(item => item.Title.ToLower() == title.ToLower());
            }
            else
            {
                Query.Where(item => item.Title.ToLower().Contains(title.ToLower()));
            }
        }

        // Pagination
        if (pageSize != -1) // Display all entries and disable pagination
        {
            Query.Skip(pageStart).Take(pageSize);
        }

        // Sort
        switch (sortColumn.ToLower())
        {
            case ("title"):

                {
                    if (sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        Query.OrderBy(x => x.Title);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Title);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and Evaluator

```cs
public class CosmosDbSpecificationEvaluator<T>: SpecificationEvaluatorBase<T> where T: class {}

//Below is the Repository method

private IQueryable<T> ApplySpecification(ISpecification<T> specification)
{
    CosmosDbSpecificationEvaluator<T> evaluator = new CosmosDbSpecificationEvaluator<T>();
    IOrderedQueryable<T> cosmosDBItems = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>();
    return evaluator.GetQuery(cosmosDBItems, specification);
}

public async Task < IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(ISpecification<T> specification) {
    IQueryable <T> queryable = ApplySpecification(specification);
    FeedIterator<T> iterator = queryable.ToFeedIterator();
    List<T> results = new List<T>();

    while (iterator.HasMoreResults) {
        FeedResponse<T> response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();

        results.AddRange(response.ToList());
    }

    return results;
}
```

Below is the Controller implementation

```cs
[HttpGet("/search/title/{SearchString}", Name = "GetAllByTitle")]
[EnableQuery]
[ApiConventionMethod(typeof (DefaultApiConventions), nameof(DefaultApiConventions.Get))]
public async Task<IEnumerable<ToDoItem>> GetAllByTitle(string SearchString) 
{
    ToDoItemSearchSpecification specification = new ToDoItemSearchSpecification(SearchString);

    IEnumerable<ToDoItem> result = await _repo.GetItemsAsync(specification);

    return result;
}
```

And it is being called like mentioned below

> https://localhost:7110/search/title/Get%200%20beers

I am trying to understand where the query is applied. Cosmos Database or Application Memory? and what does the below line do?

```cs
FeedIterator<T> iterator = queryable.ToFeedIterator();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is applied as an SQL query on the database side.
The Cosmos database will only return documents that satisfy the WHERE clause.